# How to access PDFs from a DLL and display it on Adobe PDF Reader Control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, embedded-resource

I have a WPF Window which should display PDF files which I've embedded into an DLL file. (So that it won't be accessible and visible from outside, also to keep it clean as there over 1000 files).

I was able to get the file locations by this statement: `pack://application:,,,/SampleClass;component/PDFs/`

But when I give this location to Adobe PDF Control like this: `axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(fileloc)`. It is not loading anything. So is there any proper way to access it? or another way to embed files safely?

Comment: The control expects a file path. What you posted is a resource path, not a file path. Unless that control is a WPF control it doesn't know how to handle WPF resource paths.

Comment: BTW *which* control are you using? `axAcroPDF1` suggests this is a COM control and so won't know anything about WPF.

Comment: I embedded Adobe Reader into WinFormsHost and trying to access it. Is there anyway to make that resource path available to other controls as file paths?